# couldn't match type 'ByteString o0 m0 Value' Vs 'ByteString Data.Void.Void IO Value'

Tags: json, haskell

I am trying the [haskell-json-service](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/json-web-service). When I run the code, it throws error here:

```
app req sendResponse = handle (sendResponse . invalidJson) $ do
    value <- sourceRequestBody req $$ sinkParser json
    newValue <- liftIO $ modValue value
    sendResponse $ responseLBS
        status200
        [("Content-Type", "application/json")]
        $ encode newValue
```

Error is,

```
Couldn't match type ‘conduit-1.2.4:Data.Conduit.Internal.Conduit.ConduitM
                           ByteString o0 m0 Value’
                  with ‘conduit-1.2.4.1:Data.Conduit.Internal.Conduit.ConduitM
                          ByteString Data.Void.Void IO Value’
NB: ‘conduit-1.2.4:Data.Conduit.Internal.Conduit.ConduitM’
          is defined in ‘Data.Conduit.Internal.Conduit’
              in package ‘conduit-1.2.4’
        ‘conduit-1.2.4.1:Data.Conduit.Internal.Conduit.ConduitM’
          is defined in ‘Data.Conduit.Internal.Conduit’
              in package ‘conduit-1.2.4.1’
Expected type: conduit-1.2.4.1:Data.Conduit.Internal.Conduit.Sink
                     ByteString IO Value
      Actual type: conduit-1.2.4:Data.Conduit.Internal.Conduit.ConduitM
                     ByteString o0 m0 Value
In the second argument of ‘($$)’, namely ‘sinkParser json’
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      value <- sourceRequestBody req $$ sinkParser json
```

What does `double dollar` do? And what is this type - `ByteString o0 m0 Value`?

Comment: `$$` is a conduit connect operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be the problem:

```
conduit-1.2.4:...
conduit-1.2.4.1:...
```

Your code is using a `ByteString` type from two different versions of the `conduit` library. From the point of view of GHC, these two types are unrelated: for instance, you can not pass the first type to a library function which expects the second one.

A cause for this could be using a library X which was compiled against the "old" `conduit` and a library Y which instead was compiled against the newer version. If your program imports X and Y, you will get in trouble when passing bytestrings from X to Y or vice versa. I have no idea about what X or Y actually are.

Maybe you can recompile X or Y so that they use the same version of `conduit`.

Comment: i ran `ghc-pkg find-module Data.Conduit` command to check my local installations. The output is,                                                                                                          
`/opt/ghc/7.8.4/lib/ghc-7.8.4/package.conf.d
/home/sk/.ghc/x86_64-linux-7.8.4/package.conf.d
   conduit-1.2.4
   conduit-1.2.4.1`. It looks like `Data.Conduit` is part of haskell inbuilt libraries as well (since it is inside /opt/ghc/7.8.4/lib/.....) and my user libraries also contain `Data.Conduit` package.

Comment: No, the bit following `/opt/ghc/..` is blank, so there is no global conduit (this is a little confusing!). If you do `ghc-pkg unregister conduit-1.2.4` it will warn you what will break. You should probably unregister those things too, and then conduit-1.2.4. You might go deeper and unregister everything that depends on the newer conduit too.